# Why is the solr synonym filter not working?

Tags: solr

All I am trying to do is utilize the Solr SynonymFilterFactory in my schema.xml:

```
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" omitNorms="false">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

synonyms.txt:

```
american, greek
```

When the input string is `american` it does not find the `greek food` string in the resultset.
 But, when I type in `greek` it finds `greek food`

Is there something wrong in my settings or in my synonyms file?

Thanks

Comment: Old thread here, but having the same issue.  I just changed to a WhitespaceTokenizerFactory as well.  Wondering if that has something to do with it.

Answer (score 2):

The only think I can spot is that you are using synonyms both on query and indexing which is unnecessary. Try using the synonyms **only** on query time. *

I strongly recommend the Solr query analysis GUI to debug these kind of relevance issues. It can be found in the main Solr Admin GUI. Just follow the link called analysis.

*Ps, there are lots of good discussion regarding if you should use synonyms on query or index time. Its a long and complicated discussion not suited for this answer.

Good luck!

Comment: Can you give an example of how you would use the Analysis tool in Solr? I used Field name = text and provided one half of the synonym.

Comment: I would follow the tutorial and read the small section regarding analysis.

http://lucene.apache.org/solr/tutorial.html

Answer (score 0):

For others coming across this, I had test case: 
donkey,eeore

In the analysis GUI for query donkey I was expecting eeore. I was not getting this. Was only getting "donkey." Thought I may need to change the tokenizer.

However it was expand=true - I had false. Docs say that if expand = false, it will only match first synonym from a line. I set it to true and it worked as I expected.